# appcelerator 5.1.0 ws/bufferutil build error

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-cli

I tried to install appcelerator today on Win7. All I get is "Appcelerator CLI is installing or upgrading, please wait....".

installing by cli with

```
npm install appcelerator -g
```

fails with the following output. I tried installing 5.0.0 and got a different error message. Any ideas?

```
Finding version 5.1.0 ... OK
Validating security checksum OK
Installing ... OK
Compiling platform native modules ...
└ extract-opts/typechecker ... OK
└ bunyan/dtrace-provider ...  OK
└ extract-opts/typechecker ...  OK
└ socket.io-client/ws ...  OK
└ appc-ldapjs/dtrace-provider ...  OK
└ bunyan/dtrace-provider ...  OK
└ appc-ldapjs/dtrace-provider ...  OK
└ ws/bufferutil ... gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` fail
ed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_proces
s.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Drew\.appcelerator\install\5.1.0\package\node_modules\arro
w\node_modules\appc-pubsub\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-
client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v5.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bufferutil@1.2.1" "--production"
npm ERR! node v5.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bufferutil@1.2.1 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bufferutil package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bufferutil
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved

I had to uninstall appcelerator and node.js. Then delete %APPDATA%npn and npn-cache. Then install appcelerator.

appcelerator also doesn't like it if you install jdk after installing jre.

Comment: Could you accept your own answer for others to see this has been resolved? The JRE/JDK issue is tracked at the Appcelerator JIRA already here: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-7692

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall the node version. Open Appcelerator Studio, it will automatically install the node version. Next using command prompt run below commands:

- npm install appcelerator -g
- appc use latest

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.robertkehoe.com/2015/03/fix-node-gyp-rebuild-error-on-windows/ which might help as well.  Windows and node/node-gyp are a bit of a current challenge that the node community is dealing with right now.